# Hopfield Network in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Is it possible to implement a Hopfield network through Keras, or even TensorFlow? Something like `newhop` in `MATLAB`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple numpy implementation of a Hopfield Network applying the Hebbian learning rule to reconstruct letters after noise has been added:

https://github.com/CCD-1997/hello_nn/tree/master/Hopfield-Network

Depending on your particular use case, there is the general [Recurrent Neural Network](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) architecture support in Tensorflow, mainly geared towards language modelling. Additionally, [Keras offers RNN support](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) too.